# how to move a div down in respect of slide of other div?

Tags: jquery

I am doing one drop down menu which have 2 text box and and button .i have one button on top of website . when someone clicks on that a div is sliding down.This much i done . I need to know how to take that button down with the slide of div .... please help me ..

This is my jquery code for sliding down the div

```
       $('.link_sign_in').click(function(){

                var left=$('.link_sign_in').position().left;
                var top=$('.link_sign_in').position().top;

                $(".drop_down").css("left",left-235);
                $(".drop_down").css("top",0);
                $('.drop_down').slideDown();

                });
```

css of drop_down which complete dropdown box

```
.drop_down{
        background-color: #ffffff;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        z-index:100;
        top :200px;
        left:200px;
        position: absolute;
        border: 2px solid #F8C82A;


        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 8px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        box-shadow:         0px 8px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);

        border-top: none;
        }
```

code off sign in div

```
.link_sign_in,.link_sign_up{
        cursor:pointer;
        float:left; 
        width:50px;
        margin-left:5px;
        border: 2px solid #f8c82a;
        padding:5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top: none;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 8px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        box-shadow:         0px 8px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
        }
```

Comment: please fill a jsfiddle or jsbin example showing your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Add `* { position:relative;}` to the top of your CSS document. This will cause ALL page elements to be relative to their parent, which overrides the default behavior of some browsers. Then, make sure that the button is actually a CHILD of a container that contains both the div you want to slide down AND the button. Then, use `left:20px;` or other measurements (using `top` or `bottom` or `right` if needed) to position the button where you want it. Then, when you "slide" the div down, apply the slide to the container div which contains your button and sliding div. That way, BOTH the button and the div will slide down, and the button will remain in the position you wanted it to be relative to the sliding div.

Comment: Why the need to position ALL elements in position: relative?

Comment: Because that is the desired default behavior, and not all browsers will do this by default. Therefore, to ensure that your elements are relative to their parents when using `position` you can apply that root selector and stop assuming that the browser will do that. I ran into this problem myself one time, and ever since I don't make assumptions or let the browser developers choose where to position my elements.